# Compute similarity of all elements in a list, to a single sentence

Tags: python, string, comparison

1. I need to quantify the similarity of all the sentences in a long list, to a single sentence. Perhaps using Levenshtein or difflib.
2. Then, I have to remove those sentences of the list that exceed some given threshold, by, say, 90% in difflib.

Could you guys help?
Thanks!

Comment: Good luck, Levenshtein or difflib are excellent places to start.  Get cracking!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> mylist = ['ham and eggs', 'spam and legs', "it's time to die, mr bond!"]
>>> import difflib
>>> close_matches = difflib.get_close_matches('spam and eggs', mylist)
>>> close_matches
['spam and legs', 'ham and eggs']
>>> set(mylist) - set(close_matches)
set(["it's time to die, mr bond!"])
```

Comment: +1 - `difflib` looks like an interesting module, thanks for opening my eyes to it!

Comment: Thanks wim! It's a nice solution. I need however to remove the close_matches that exceed certain numeric threshold as given by: seq = difflib.SequenceMatcher(sentence,list)...

Comment: You should give it a try yourself and edit your question if and where you get stuck.  It is not too hard to modify my example to use a `difflib.SequenceMatcher` class instead of `difflib.get_close_matches` worker function.

Comment: Try for example looking at the result of `[difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, 'spam and eggs', x).ratio() for x in mylist]`